# Vertical alignment gets broken

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, semantic-ui

I have my login form centered vertically as described in the docs using `middle alligned`, however, if I place a dynamic content within the centered block (e.g `{{message}}`, message being a helper) it breaks the centering and the block is aligned to top.

Is there any way around it?

Comment: There are many reasons why this might be happening.  Please post the code/markup you are using or a link to a repo.  Without that, it's basically impossible to help you.

Comment: @andersr when preparing the project that would demostrate the issue I found out the reason. Using `center aligned` on the grid directly breaks the alignment. `middle aligned centered grid` works as expected. I ended up marking the column with `center aligned` instead of the grid.